# Matlab colormap symmetric about 1

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, colormap

I have data that is constructed as a ratio, and therefore I'd like to use a red/white/blue colormap where white is assigned to 1 and red and blue surround it. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily construct a blue-white-read colormap using `interp1`. Here's a little anonymous function which takes an integer as input and constructs a colormap.

```
bwr = @(n)interp1([1 2 3], [0 0 1; 1 1 1; 1 0  0], linspace(1, 3, n), 'linear')
colormap(bwr(64));
```

To control where the white calls, you'll want to set the `CLim` of the axes. You will want to center your clims around the value that you want to be white.

```
set(gca, 'clim', [0 2])
```

And as a full example:

```
data = reshape(linspace(0, 100, 16), [4 4]) ./ 50;
figure
imagesc(data);
colormap(bwr(64));
colorbar;
set(gca, 'clim', [0 2])
```

[image]

Keep in mind though that since you have a ratio, all of the values between 0 and 1 will be compressed whereas the values > 1 can theoretically go all the way to infinity. 
As an example:

```
data = reshape(linspace(1, 200, 16), [4 4]) ./ 50;
```

[image]

To correct for this you could log-transform your data prior to plotting and then change the colorbar tick marks to represent your initial ratio values.

```
LData = log(data);
imagesc(LData)
colormap(bwr(64));

cbar = colorbar();

set(gca, 'clim', [-1 1] * max(abs(LData(:))))

cticks = get(cbar, 'Ticks');
cticklabels = arrayfun(@(x)sprintf('%0.2f', x), exp(cticks), 'uniformoutput', false);
set(cbar, 'TickLabels', cticklabels);
```

[image]